# How to Create URL friendly route and remove index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I know how to create a URL friendly route and i also know how to remove index. But I'm wondering how do I combine the two together?

Using this tutorial https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/generate-seo-friendly-urls-aspnet-mvc/ I was able to add the following code to allow for url friendly routes.

```
routes.Add("ProductDetails", new SeoFriendlyRoute("drink/{id}",
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Drink", action = "Index" }),
    new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

So instead of my url being `test.com/index/drink/1` it now becomes `test.com/index/drink/coke`

The next set of code I have is to remove the index from the url.

```
routes.MapRoute("DrinkRoute",
    "drink/{id}",
    new { controller = "Drink", action = "Index" });
```

This will succesfully convert `test.com/index/drink/1` to `test.com/drink/1`

May I ask how do I combine the two together so that I can have a route that will lead me to the correct controller action and display `test.com/drink/coke`

RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also achieve the same using attribute routing which would provide more control of the desired routes.

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

First you would need to enable attribute routing by calling `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` in your `RouteConfig`. Make sure it is registered before convention-based routes.

```
public class RouteConfig {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //Attribute routes
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        //Default convention-based routes
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

With attribute routing enabled you can specify your routes by annotating your actions and controllers.

```
[RoutePrefix("drink")]
public class DrinkController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{name}")] // GET drink/coke
    public ActionResult Index(string name) {

        //...use name to get model

        return View();
    }

    //..
}
```

The above `DrinkController.Index` action is now mapped to `GET drink/coke` assuming `test.com` is the host of the controller as shown in your example.

Any controllers or actions not annotated by routing attributes will default back to the convention based routes (if any) registered in the routing table.

This means that you can have a mix of convention-based and attribute-based routes defined for your controllers.

Note however that once you use the attribute routes on a controller that you will have to use it on all its public actions.

Comment: what if we want to pass Id here as well but do not want to show in URL

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can achieve desired behavior with `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DrinkRoute",
            url: "drink/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Drink", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

In that case the url `test.com/drink/coke` will be hit with the controller `DrinkController.cs` and the action method `Index`. Id will be `coke`. Source code of this controller:

```
public class DrinkController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Ivan, I can't simply just delete the original default map route. Other controllers rely on it.

Comment: As Ivan's edit shows, you can register any number of route patterns, and whichever is registered first and matches the given route is what will be used.  Aka you can have `url: "drink/new"` registered before `url: "drink/{id}"` and have `id` be of type string, and you'll never see a hit to that second route's method with a string "new"

Comment: The main problem with this solution is that i would have to change every single Method to now take a `string id` instead of an `int id`. So i think a better solution would be to reconfig routing instead of having to change every single method in my controllers

Comment: What do you mean? Your example url is `test.com/drink/coke` where `coke` is obviously string. "change every single method in my controllers" - The non-default routing will work only for one controller - `DrinkController`, default routing will be applyed for others controllers.

Comment: if you had taken a look at this link i posted https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/generate-seo-friendly-urls-aspnet-mvc/ you'll know that an int gets passed instead of a string.

Comment: Of course I had taken look at this post. In that post the example of url is `localhost:55978/Products/Details/8-sony-slt-a77-ii` and the `SeoFriendlyRoute` class extracts the int id (the first digit 8) from url with `Regex` and passes it to controller. But in your example of url is 'test.com/drink/coke' without any numbers. And you accepted the answer in which the action method also has the signuture `public ActionResult Index(string name)` with string parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the SEO Routes and give your action or controller full control:

```
public class DrinkssController : Controller
{
    [Route("drink/{drinkName}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string drinkName)
    {
        var model = _drinks.First(x => x.name == drinkName);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```